# How to access user data efficiently from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Many forums and websites display user information on posts or in tables (when you are looking at more than 1 user)

For example you might have a forum thread and each post on it displays information about the the poster like this:

Name: John
Email: email@email.com
Posts: 450

They probably have a table for users which is where the name and email are stored, and then a table for posts.

The only think I can think of to do it in one sql statement would be to add 1 to a row (the one that corresponds to the user making the post) in the user table each time the user posted which seems like a bad solution to me.

How do they count the number of posts for each user?

Comment: Why do you think that incrementing a counter in the user row is a bad solution? I think it's actually better than counting the posts of every user every time a post is showed.

Comment: maxhud, you should really accept nick's answer, it is by far the more correct one, as he mentioned as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use the SQL [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) function to dynamically generate the count:

```
SELECT COUNT( *) FROM posts WHERE user_id = 1
```

This will count the number of rows in the `posts` table which were written by users who match the criteria `user_id = 1`.

To do this in one query, you can use a JOIN, and GROUP BY the identifier, like so:

```
SELECT username, user_email, COUNT( p.post_id) as num_posts
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN posts p
    ON p.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = 1
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Comment: thank you. i am only selecting the other answer because it was first and is more simple

Comment: It matters which answer is correct and applicable, not whose is first (which mine was, btw). I'm pretty sure (note:pretty sure) the other answer will not return a 0 count for users who have no posts, which is likely undesirable.

Comment: wow that's embarrassing that i read that wrong. fair enough. His example is easier to understand. Why does yours return a 0?

Comment: Because it counts only post_id, your counts *. Also, your example will not return users with no posts.

Comment: Not "your" example. I mean krakover's example. (not time to edit, sorry)

Comment: I think you meant to group by u.user_id

Comment: Well, you are right that @krakover's answer cannot possibly return users with 0 posts, but it is highly unlikely that those users would actually appear in the output when displaying a post (if they don't have posts, they can't be among the particular posters being requested, no need to do a left join). So left join may not be an advantage in this particular case. (But in others it certainly may.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the email is unique in the user table, you can do:

```
SELECT u.name, u.email, count(*) 
FROM users u, posts p
WHERE u.user_id = p.user_id
GROUP BY u.email;
```